# jquery swiper slider horizontal scroll working only one item

Tags: slider, swiper.js, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a horizontal scroll slider with swiper slider. I have create this slider but it is making problem on scrolling. When I scroll my mousewheel, only one slide scrolled. and other items not comming with the mouse scroll. Please see this video:
https://youtu.be/DjO4ZlRf-js

My js codes here:

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper(".hero-swiper-container", {
          loopedSlides: 6,
          loop: false,
          spaceBetween: 0,
          slidesPerView: 1,
            allowSlideNext: true,
             allowSlidePrev: true,
          mousewheel: true,
            releaseOnEdges: true,
          navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
              prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Thank you

I am trying with this code:

```
<script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var swiper = new Swiper(".hero-swiper-container", {
          loopedSlides: 6,
          loop: false,
          spaceBetween: 0,
          slidesPerView: 1,
            allowSlideNext: true,
             allowSlidePrev: true,
          mousewheel: true,
            releaseOnEdges: true,
          navigation: {
              nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
              prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
```